INST_RETIRED.ANY no longer works as a performance counter with perf on linux 6.7
With the older kernels INST_RETIRED.ANY (as well as many of the other counters documented in https://perfmon-events.intel.com/ahybrid.htm ) worked as counters for perf.
I am now using perf with a 6.7 kernel running on a  Sapphire Rapids {Golden Cove} processor.
When I do the following
 perf stat -e INST_RETIRED.ANY,cycles sleep 2

I get
event syntax error: 'INST_RETIRED.ANY,cycles'
                     \___ parser error

Is this the expected behavior?

The reason  INST_RETIRED.ANY returned a parse error was that the version of perf did not match the version of Linux, as it must.
I was given the machine by someone who I assumed set it up properly, so I did not bother to check for version mismatches. Fortunately a commentor suggested to check the version of perf, which turned out to solve the problem

At least when I run sudo perf list and look for inst_retired, I find inst_retired.any, which fits the capitalization convention of the other events. So, chances are that these were renamed in the tools. I can run
perf stat -e inst_retired.any,cycles sleep 2

and get

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 2':

         1.600.192      inst_retired.any
         2.142.871      cycles

       2,001396579 seconds time elapsed

       0,000000000 seconds user
       0,001231000 seconds sys



on this intel (not gen12/13) machine.

What you're seeing is what I used to see on older systems. Something seems to have changed with the Sapphire Rapids processor on Linux 6.7. Are you running 6.7?  If so, then the change is with Sapphire Rapids.  If you're not running 6.7 then we don't know if the newer kernel caused the change in behavior,  or the newer processor caused the change in behavior.

just to be sure: you did see the difference in capitalization between what I typed and what you typed? Yes, I'm on Linux 6.7.5.

But this really has nothing to do with the kernel version (if it was, you'd be getting "Bad event name"); the fact that your event is in ALL_CAPS is what is causing the userland tool to fail parsing your -e list

Upper case isn't the problem, because I get the parser error with the lower case version. Also perf list does not show inst_retired.any as a valid event, but it also didn't when I ran on older systems. So it appears that Sapphire Rapids breaks this.

this is very confusing and it sounds like a bug in the perf tool that it shows "Parser error" in that case? What do you get when you run perf --version? (I get perf version 6.7.10-200.fc39.x86_64)

I think you found the problem. perf was installed when I was given this machine, so I assumed that perf was installed properly.  However the perf version turned out to be  4.18.0-477.10.1.el8_8.x86_64. I'll install the proper version tomorrow and I'm sure that should fix things. Thanks for your help.

@rkg125 if that turns out to solve the problem, please post an answer post here and accept it, so that others see your is solved. Answering your own questions is much appreciated here! (don't edit your question to include an answer, post it as answer just as I did)
